# Viewstate becomes empty after 30 minutes of idle time

Tags: asp.net, session, sharepoint, drop-down-menu, viewstate

I have a SharePoint site.  We have some web parts rendering ascx controls.

Session time out and IIS idle time out is set to 2 hours (120 mins) in web config and iis settings.  I have confirmed that session does not time out
After 30 minutes of idle time the drop downs and check box list in application becomes empty
I had Visual studio debugger attached to my application and had the application idle for 30 minutes to see what is happening.  After 30 mins when I try to post back, I watched variables in the debugger.  I found the session variables were alive and had values.  However the drop down and ViewState variables were empty.

We are using SQL server sessions.  I am clueless and have spent nights on this issue but seem to get no where.

Comment: You might want to read this 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-1.aspx

Comment: Gr8.  Turns out the second page of this post tells about FormDigestSettings.TimeOut of web application and that is exactly what controls viewstate timing in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is in the Part 2 of the article that Nicholas posted.
Turns out that web application has a setting that can be controlled through Powershell

$web = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mywebapp..."
$web.FormDigestSettings.TimeOut

This is by default 30 minutes and SharePoint Viewstate cache is cleared after 
FormDigestSettings.TimeOut +1 (i.e. 31 minutes)

$web.FormDigestSettings.TimeOut = New-TimeSpan -Hours 1 -Minutes 0

Increasing this time out might have some performance implications hence encourage you to read the article .

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-2.aspx